# Invalid login attempt. when login identity asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I using this code for check login :

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
        {
            ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on.";
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

when I login show me this error : `Invalid login attempt.` but Email and password has exist .

This code :

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
```

Not null but this code is Failure :

```
 var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

whats the problem ? How solve this problem ?

Comment: is the password correct?

Comment: yes . its correct

Comment: Does this happen for all user accounts or for just one specific user account?

Comment: for all user . . .

Comment: Ok, how is the password being stored in the database? Is it encrypted, hashed or cleartext? Can you show the connection string you are using to connect to the database, and the config settings related to whatever database you are using to store user credentials?

Comment: i using the mvc identity . password is hashed . i cerate a database with code first in sql server 2014 . it `FindByEmailAsync` if first step .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125323/discussion-between-kianoush-and-user1666620).

Comment: It's better to find the user by UserManager.FindByName(newUser.Username). Maybe several same email had been register.

Comment: @FereydoonBarikzehy when i using this not find any thing

Comment: if UserManager.FindByName(newUser.Username) does not find user it means the user is not registered in identity.

Comment: yea . user is register i database

Comment: @Kianoush is the username the same as the email address field in the database?

Comment: it work by username . but ineed use by email .

Comment: @user1666620 no , they difrent

Comment: @Kianoush use email to find user and then use the user's username to sign in. that is how the signinmanager works. unless you make the email and username the same.

Comment: @Nkosi they not same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have already found a valid user via email then use the username of the found user to sign in.

```
//...
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
if (user != null) {
    if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)) {
        ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on.";
        return View("Error");
    }
}
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
//...
```

Comment: i need use the email for login

Comment: technically you are signing in with email. You used the email to find the user account. and then used the information of that account along with provided password to sign in. This is how I use Identity to sign in my users..

Answer (score -1):

In the `registrationConfirmation` put `user.emailconfirmed = true` during the development phase. When you migrate to production remove this code.

Comment: I know if someone will try to look for the the same problem solution, he will find the required solution.

Comment: Why should it be a problem to respond to "old" questions? Is there something written in SO guidelines? I have seen often negative comments or even downvotes, when someone is reacting on an old question.